# "size_t" as type parameter, cast warning not reproduced

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++-2005, size-t, visual-studio

I've been trying to get rid of warnings in some older code (must use MSVC 2005, currently working with a 32 bit build), but have been struggling to **get rid of a `size_t` to `unsigned int` conversion warning**. We have our own `Array<T>`  implementation of a growing array that implements an

`template<typename I> const T& at(const I i) const {return atImpl(i);}`

method. When called as

`size_t i = 10; myArray.at(i);`

I get a `conversion from 'size_t' to 'const unsigned int', possible loss of data` warning. A **working theory has been** that `I` is understood to be `unsigned int`, which is causing compiler to cast/convert the `size_t` to `unsigned int` when passing `i` to `at` (which would have been inconvenient but acceptable). However, I **haven't been able to reproduce this warning in neither a minimal working example** (bottom of this post), nor in more complex minimal examples. Simply casting the parameter to `unsigned int` makes the warning disappear and would be enough for our needs (by contract, the number fits within an `unsigned int`)

1. Is my understanding about `I` being `unsigned int` in such a call correct (spec says "*A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type. A typedef-name does
   not introduce a new type*", `typeid(size_t(1)).name()` says `unsigned int`  and `size_t` seems to be `typedef`fed). In other words, should or should not the minimal example give the warning? The build configuration is the same, as far as I can tell.
2. As our code gives us warnings and the minimal example doesn't, there's something I must be overlooking. Despite all effort, I can't figure out what. Ideas?

Thanks

The minimal example:

```
    template<typename T>
    class A
    {
      int t;
    public:
      template<typename I> T& at(const I i) { return t;}  
    };

    int main()
    {  
      size_t i = 10;
      A<int> a; 
      a.at(i) = 5; // no warning, why?
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you by any chance using the `/Wp64` option? It would warn that `size_t` has a different size in 64-bit mode, but `unsigned int` does not.

Comment: If you are working on making the code portable, you should consider using `std::size_t` on your `MyVector` type anyway, rather than thinking whether the warning makes sense. One day or another you will change architectures (64bit) and `size_t` might be a different size and you will have to comeback and revisit all the warnings...
Unless, of course, the argument is not used to access a container but to store in some other form.

Comment: If `atImpl` takes `unsigned`, then could the warning stem from `atImpl(i)` which does in fact do an `std::size_t` to `unsigned` conversion when passed an `std::size_t` argument?

Comment: Okay, question: Why the heck do you have your own `std::vector` implementation?

Comment: @CharlesBailey yes, I'm using /Wp64

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas My first impression is that you are right about having `std::size_t` as perhaps the sole possiblity, instead of having a template.

Comment: @LucDanton Hmm, could you explain, please? Since `atImpl(i)` is actually called from within `at`, how could it produce a warning at the line with `at`, instead of inside `at` itself?

Comment: @Xeo Multiple dimensions, with the number being definable at run time, is my guess after working with the source for a few days. I think there are other uses as well, depends on your circumstances. As for an answer: And I'm not too keen on people answering "How do you get to France" with "Why do you want to go to France"

Comment: If you are using `/Wp64` then you probably want to turn it off. It is known to create spurious warnings in some cases (such as yours). If you care about 64-bit portability it is much better to compile with an actual 64-bit compiler with normal warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The at function is also templated.  C++ will try to deduce the template type argument.  Which is what is happening in your code since you are not specifying the type in the call such as a.at< size_t>(1);

This code will generate a warning because it has deduced the type as a unsigned int and then we try to pass an size_t

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    int t;
    public:
        template<typename I> T& at(const I i)
        { return t;}
};

int main()
{
    unsigned int j = 5;
    size_t i = 10;
    A<int> a;

    a.at(j) = 4; // deduce template type as unsigned int
    a.at(i) = 5; // generate warning
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I actually tried this code in VS and it generates the warning.

**Edit2:** In the code I tried size_t and unsigned int are both also 4 bytes.  So I did some digging.  In older versions of VS size_t is defined as `typedef __w64 unsigned int size_t`  The '__w64' is now deprecated but was used to flag types that would have a different size (eg 64 vs 32) when moving to a 64 bit platform.  The __w64 causes the compiler to see `size_t` as a different type.

As an experiment I typedefed my own unsigned int `myint` and changed the line `size_t i = 10` to `myint i = 10`.

using `typedef __w64 unsigned int myint` generates the warning where as 'typedef unsigned int myint` does not generate a warning.

Comment: I think this is it. For further reference, it seems that since `size_t`  amounts to `unsigned int` in my configuration, both `at(size_t(1))` and `at((unsigned int)2)` would instantiate and reuse the same version of `at` (as both are synonyms under my current configuration). If `a.at(j);a.at(i);` is used, a `unsigned int` version of `at` is instantiated, and then, due to the equivalence, reused by the `a.at(i);` reference, which triggers the warning. If `a.at(i);a.at(j);` is used, a `size_t` version is inst. and reused by the `a.at(j)` reference, no problem/warn. Correct? Great find!

Comment: That is a good summation. You are also correct if the a.at(i) would have been called first, when a.at(j) is called the unsigned int is promoted to size_t (unsigned long) without loss of data.

Comment: Actually, to be clear, I'm talking about a 32 bit build, where `sizeof(i) == sizeof(j)`, so there would not, afaik, be any promotion taking place. The rest still hold, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Would the `explicit` keyword be useful in this case?  Would it even be valid?  (I haven't used it much, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: HazaB, I see. I think I would defer back to the comments above. Is it possible your build has redefined size_t?  Perhaps to a signed value.

Comment: @Charlie hmm, interesting; as for the "_The `__w64` causes the compiler to see size_t as a different type._", do you mean that literally (they both seems to use the same instance of `at`), if so, what's your source? Or did you just mean to say it makes the compiler flag conversions between otherwise synonymous types?

Comment: I am starting to stretch my understanding and am not sure I can answer your question.  From the experiment I know adding __w64 causes the compiler to generate the warning.  However, is it because the compiler literally thinks they are two different types or the __w64 just causes the compiler to always create a warning? I am not sure.   Either way, it is meeting the initial outset of micrsoft. "Warn users were they may have problems when they go to 64-bit."  It has also uncovered that your code is inconsistently invoking the at function.